# How can `limma` be used to determine genes predictive of a given phenotype?

Tags: r, gene, gene-expression, limma

Using `limma` within Bioconductor [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html), which is a linear model package for microarray data and `lmFit` on gene expression data, I can perform a series of regressions `gene ~ covariates` by specifying `design = model.matrix(~ covariates)` and calling `lmFit(eset, design)`.

How can I instead run the regressions `phenotype ~ gene + covariates`?

Comment: I think you can ask this question better at [bioc support site](https://support.bioconductor.org/). There the developers of limma can answer you.